# Django query result SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying a query in django shell that compares the username against a user given in a variable.

**variable**

```
usuario = 'john.doe'
```

**query**

```
EncabezadoReporte.objects.filter('user__username'= usuario)
```

and I get the following error:

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

my understanding is that everything before '=' is a keyword parameter, I don´t understando how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not define keyword arguments as strings. You do not need the `''` around the `user__username`. The proper way to set a keyword argument is simply write what that keyword argument is equal to like such: `EncabezadoReporte.objects.filter(user__username= usuario)`